# Remove outdated content from google, when indexed url does not contain "www"

Tags: google-search-console

I am trying to remove a link from google via https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals

The issue is, that indexed link is https://example.com/url, and not https://www.example.com/url.

When I try to submit url without WWW, it throws an error (invalid link).
The one with WWW is acceppted sucessfully and removed, but this does not help me, because google is still  indexing one without www.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Google Console manages the www / non-www / http / https versions of a domain separately, so you need to apply the url removal for the property without www in your case.

Have you added both www and non www properties (urls) to your google console? If not, then you first need to add (and verify) the https://example.com/ property as well and do the url removal when that property is selected, not the www one.

[Here you find more info](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en), that also helps to decide, which verification method (important!) you should choose.